# Active tab not displaying above the image in vertical tabs layout in HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css, web, bootstrap-4

I am working on a web page with a vertical tabs layout, where each tab corresponds to an image and some content. The issue I'm facing is that the active tab doesn't come above the image as expected.

I have tried adjusting the z-index values for the active and non-active links, but it doesn't seem to work as intended. The active tab's background should cover the image, but it remains behind it.

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
<div class="container d-flex justify-content-center mt-20">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 mb-5">
            <div class="tab-vertical">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab3" role="tablist">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" id="home-vertical-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home-vertical" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">---- HOSPITALITY MANAGEMENT </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" id="profile-vertical-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile-vertical" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Tab Vertical #2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" id="contact-vertical-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact-vertical" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Tab Vertical #3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xl-9 col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 mb-5">
            <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent3">
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home-vertical" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-vertical-tab">
                    <div class="image-container">
                        <img src="./assets/img/service1.png" alt="Image 1">
                        <div class="content-bottom-left">Content here</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile-vertical" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-vertical-tab">
                    <div class="image-container">
                        <img src="./assets/img/service1.png" alt="Image 2">
                        <div class="content-bottom-left">Content here</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact-vertical" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-vertical-tab">
                    <div class="image-container">
                        <img src="./assets/img/service1.png" alt="Image 3">
                        <div class="content-bottom-left">Content here</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>.tab-vertical .nav.nav-tabs {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 0px;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.tab-vertical .nav.nav-tabs .nav-item {
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  width: 120px; /* Adjust the width as needed */
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tab-vertical .nav-tabs .nav-link {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-top-left-radius: .25rem;
  border-top-right-radius: .25rem;
  padding: 17px 49px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 30vw; /* Set the width to 100% */
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 4px;
  border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 4px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1; /* Higher z-index for non-active links */
}

.tab-vertical .nav-tabs .nav-link.active {
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 5; /* Higher z-index for active link */
  background-color: transparent;
}

.tab-vertical .nav-tabs .nav-link {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px !important;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px !important;
}

.tab-vertical .tab-content {
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 4px;
  border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 4px;
  padding: 30px;
}

.image-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 2; /* Lower z-index for the image */
}

.image-container img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}



.content-bottom-left {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  padding: 10px;
}
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .image-container img {
      width: 70vw;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .image-container img {
      width: 50vw;
  }
}
```

I have tried adjusting the z-index values in the CSS for both the active and non-active links, but it doesn't seem to work as intended.

Could someone please help me understand why the active tab is not displaying above the image in the vertical tabs layout? Is there something I am missing or any other approach I should consider?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using z-index to control the stacking order of your tabs and images. However, there are a couple of issues in your CSS that might be causing the problem:

```
z-index on .nav-link:
```

You have set `z-index: -1`; for `.tab-vertical .nav-tabs .nav-link`. This will place the non-active links behind other elements. Consider removing this line to allow the default stacking order to be used.

```
.tab-vertical .nav-tabs .nav-link {
  z-index: -1; /* Remove or adjust this line */
}
```

`z-index` on `.image-container`:
You have set `z-index: 2;` for `.image-container`. This will place the image above the tabs. Try removing or reducing this value.

```
.image-container {
  /* ... */
  z-index: 2; /* Remove or reduce this value */
}
```

Adjusting `Z-index` for Active Tab:
Make sure the `z-index` for the active tab is higher than the other elements. You have already set this in your CSS, but make sure it's higher than the `z-index` of the image container.